# Python subprocess Popen readline before closing stdin

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe

```
import subprocess as sp

p = sp.Popen("/bin/cat", stdin=sp.PIPE, stdout=sp.PIPE)

p.stdin.write(b"foobaz!\n")
p.stdin.close()
print(p.stdout.readline())
```

This code works as expected (cat echoes the stdin, and we can read the stdout)

If we comment out the `p.stdin.close()`, the `.readline()` blocks indefinitely. This behaves the same calling `.read(1)` instead. Is there a way to readline using the subprocess module without sending EOF to stdin?

I am aware there are other libraries that might solve my problem, and am looking into them as well. For this question, I am only curious if `subprocess` has this capability, and how to achieve it through `subprocess`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the buffering.  You can use `bufsize=1` if you also use `universal_newlines=True` (though you would then write strings instead of bytes):

```
p = sp.Popen("/bin/cat", stdin=sp.PIPE, stdout=sp.PIPE, 
             bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True)
p.stdin.write("foobaz!\n")
print(p.stdout.readline())
```

The above is tested in Python 3.5.2.  Note - I have separately just read an answer to unrelated question that suggests that in more recent Python versions `text=True` is equivalent of `universal_newlines=True`, but don't have a more recent installation to try it with at time of writing.